# Simple php twitter app

Tags: php, twitter

I'm looking something simple in php for update a status of my user, like a bot.

All lib's are complicated or complex, and simple's haven't update to aouth autentication.

You know som lib for update status in twitter? not for make app twitter, just send update status with a cron.

**Edit**
I found this example very simple:

http://ditio.net/2010/06/07/twitter-php-oauth-update-status/

with this lib:
https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async

Comment: Suggestion: add your "edit" as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

The quick way to post a new status with [TwitterOAuth](https://twitteroauth.com/).

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$statues = $connection->post("statuses/update", ["status" => "hello world"]);
```

Comment: :O 25K, you knew better :p Cheers, happy coding.

Comment: Haha, well that answer was from a long time ago.

Comment: Oh wow, did not even realize the timestamp - just popped up in the review queue.